# How can I solve below Flutter project creation error?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

could not find an option named "androidx". Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter -h') for available flutter commands and options.

I create project from android studio 3.6.1.

> E:\SOFTWEAR\flutter>flutter doctor -v
>   
> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.657], locale en-US)
>   
>     • Flutter version 1.5.4 at E:\SOFTWEAR\flutter
>   
>     • Framework revision b593f5167b (11 months ago), 2019-04-22 07:51:33 -0700
>       
> • Engine revision ca31a7c57b
>       
> • Dart version 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.1 cf4444b803)
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
>       
> • Android SDK at E:\SOFTWEAR\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk
>       
> • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
>   
>     • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
>   
>     • ANDROID_HOME = E:\SOFTWEAR\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk
>   
>     • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
>   
>     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
>   
>     • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
>   
>     • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
>   
>     • Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
>   
>     • Dart plugin version 192.7761
>   
>     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
>
> [√] Connected device (1 available)
>   
>     • vivo 1951 • b9dad674 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)
>
> • No issues found!

Comment: Give us more information. How are you trying to create the project? also give us the output of `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: @LoïcFonkam I edited question.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that by navigating to your flutter install directory and run

> `flutter upgrade`

There are manual update to be done, but the above command will handle that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove this error by update your **Dart** and **Flutter** plugin.

1. Just go to **file** -> **close project**
2. Click on **Configure** which is shown bottom right in the screen -> **Plugins**
3. Search **Dart** and ***update*** and then search **flutter** and ***update*** and restart studio
   4.Your problem is resolved you can create fresh project successfully